# How can I extract pin property from an object and make an array of pins in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have done it with array `PinArray.push(data.pin)`, but I am looking for a better solution.

```
let PinArray = [];

const bbb = AllPackages.forEach(p => {
    p.dealProducts
        .filter(dp => dp.product.code === 'AAA')
        .forEach(data => PinArray.push(data.pin));
});
```

```js
const AllPackages = [
      {
        Id: 1,
        dealProducts: [
          {
            pin: 'AAA000',
            product: {
              id: '100',
              code: 'AAA',
              name: 'AAA'
            }
          },
          {
            pin: 'AAA111',
            product: {
              id: '200',
              code: 'BBB',
              name: 'BBB'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        Id: 2,
        dealProducts: [
          {
            pin: '',
            product: {
              id: '300',
              code: 'CCC',
              name: 'CCC'
            }
          },
          {
            pin: '1',
            product: {
              id: '200',
              code: 'AAA',
              name: 'BBB'
            }
          },
          {
            pin: '1',
            product: {
              id: '200',
              code: 'BBB',
              name: 'BBB'
            }
          },
          {
            pin: '',
            product: {
              id: '400',
              code: 'DDD',
              name: 'DDD'
            }
          },
          {
            pin: 'AAA111',
            product: {
              id: '100',
              code: 'AAA',
              name: 'AAA'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
    
const PinArray = AllPackages.forEach(p => {
      p.dealProducts.filter(dp => dp.product.code === 'AAA')
        .forEach(data => { 
        const{pin} = data; 
        return pin; 
        });
    });

console.log(PinArray);

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: Do you only need pins for `product.code === 'AAA'`?? Or all pins?

Comment: Just for product.code === 'AAA'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can concisely get a single array of all the `dealProducts` with `flatMap`. Then `.filter` to select only those with the right code, then map to extract the pin from each:

```
const pinArray = AllPackages
  .flatMap(p => p.dealProducts)
  .filter(obj => obj.product.code === 'AAA')
  .map(data => data.pin);
```

```js
const AllPackages = [{
    Id: 1,
    dealProducts: [{
        pin: 'AAA000',
        product: {
          id: '100',
          code: 'AAA',
          name: 'AAA'
        }
      },
      {
        pin: 'AAA111',
        product: {
          id: '200',
          code: 'BBB',
          name: 'BBB'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    Id: 2,
    dealProducts: [{
        pin: '',
        product: {
          id: '300',
          code: 'CCC',
          name: 'CCC'
        }
      },
      {
        pin: '1',
        product: {
          id: '200',
          code: 'AAA',
          name: 'BBB'
        }
      },
      {
        pin: '1',
        product: {
          id: '200',
          code: 'BBB',
          name: 'BBB'
        }
      },
      {
        pin: '',
        product: {
          id: '400',
          code: 'DDD',
          name: 'DDD'
        }
      },
      {
        pin: 'AAA111',
        product: {
          id: '100',
          code: 'AAA',
          name: 'AAA'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
];

const pinArray = AllPackages
  .flatMap(p => p.dealProducts)
  .filter(obj => obj.product.code === 'AAA')
  .map(data => data.pin);
console.log(pinArray);
```

Comment: Can you please explain why my code doesn't work?

Comment: Your original code does work, right? Your second code doesn't because `forEach` always returns `undefined`. `forEach` also ignores the value returned in its callback.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you could do something like this:

```
const PinArray3 = AllPackages.flatMap((p) => p.dealProducts).reduce(
   (acc, dealProduct) => (dealProduct.product.code === "AAA" ? [...acc, dealProduct.pin] : acc), 
   []
);
```

Comment: You code is returning ["AAA", "AAA", "AAA"] which is not values for pins.

Comment: I updated my answer, now it should run fine :)